# Auto fill a text box with database information without leaving a page

Tags: php, javascript, sql, sql-server, ajax

I have several forms on a page and they have to be filled in automatically by accessing a users ID and then filling the rest of the text boxes with the necessary information. Essentially an auto fill for the forms dependent on which RFID is entered into the first text box.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php
$con = mssql_connect("123", "abc", "pass");
if (!$con)
  {
 die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());
  }

mssql_select_db("db1", $con);

$result = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM Scrabble");
$row = array("RFID" => "", "Tile" => "", "TileScore" => "");

$row = mssql_fetch_row($result)

?>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="RFID1"/> 
    <input type="text" name="Tile1"/> 
    <input type="text" name="TileScore1"/> 
    <input type ="button" value="submit" onclick="RFID1.disabled=true" />

    <td><input type="text" name="RFID2"/> 
    <input type="text" name="Tile2"/> 
    <input type="text" name="TileScore2"/> 
    <input type ="button" value="submit" onclick="RFID2.disabled=true" />

    <input type="text" name="RFID3"/> 
    <input type="text" name="Tile3"/> 
    <input type="text" name="TileScore3"/> 
    <input type ="button" value="submit" onclick="RFID3.disabled=true" />
    <form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I need it to take the Tile and TileScore from where the RFID is equal to what is entered in the text box. Is this possible without having to submit the page to allow the other forms to be filled in as well? I've been told it may be possible using AJAX but am unaware of a solution.

This is using MSSQL, sadly there isn't an MSSQL tag.

Comment: what textbox is this (RFID) being entered into? Also what is your SQL code trying to do?

Comment: Some minor problems here as well: `<form>` is not being closed, as well as random `<td>` before "RFID2"; also why is $row declared as an array if it is overwritten before being used?

Comment: There is a [tag:sql-server] tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I'm assuming that the way you want your page to function is that the user types into the `RFID` text-field.

To make the code simpler and more flexible I've changed the three form-like segments into three separate forms. This also has an added advantage that if the browser doesn't support JavaScript the page falls back to submitting the form.

I could not make sense of the SQL so I have merely commented it out.

I have also added some extra PHP throughout the page, so that in case of javascript not being available the submitted page will still respond with the form correctly.

To add in your SQL query code, just make sure the resulting `Tile` and `TileScore` are placed in variables `$tile` and `$tileScore` respectively.

### Code

```
<?php
/*
function sqlStuff(){
$con = mssql_connect('123', 'abc', 'pass');
if(!$con){die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_get_last_message());}
mssql_select_db('db1', $con);
$result = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM Scrabble');
// Why is the following here?
$row = array('RFID' => '', 'Tile' => '', 'TileScore' => '');
$row = mssql_fetch_row($result)
}
*/
$rfid=$_GET['RFID'];
$tile='Tile for "'.$rfid.'"';
$tileScore='TileScore for "'.$rfid.'"';

$separ='/'; //separator

// if this is an ajax request do the following, if not print the page as normal
if($_GET['r']=='ajax'){
    $ajaxString=$separ.$tile;
    $ajaxString.=$separ.$tileScore;
    echo $ajaxString;
}else{
// which form was submitted, only used if form was submitted by browser.
$form=$_GET['form'];
// escape quote characters
$rfid=htmlentities($rfid);
$tile=htmlentities($tile);
$tileScore=htmlentities($tileScore);
?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>live-submitting form using javascript!</title>
<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
body{font:80% sans-serif;}
/*]]>*/
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    window.onload=load;
    function load(){
        document.getElementById('form1').onsubmit=function(){if(submitWithJS(this)){return false;}};
        document.getElementById('form2').onsubmit=function(){if(submitWithJS(this)){return false;}};
        document.getElementById('form3').onsubmit=function(){if(submitWithJS(this)){return false;}};
    }

    function submitWithJS(thisForm){
        // setup ajax object
        var httpReq;
        if(window.XMLHttpRequest){// Non-IE
            httpReq=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }else if(window.ActiveXObject){ // IE
            try{httpReq=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
            catch(e){
                try{httpReq=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
                catch(e){
                    return false; // some other IE check?
                }
            }
        }else{
            return false; // submit without ajax
        }
        // Actual code:
        httpReq.onreadystatechange=function(){
            // basically readyState 4 is when reply is recieved
            if(this.readyState==4){responder(this,thisForm);}
        }
        // prepare args
        //beware "arguments" is a keyword
        var args="?r=ajax"; // type of request
        args+="&RFID="+thisForm.RFID.value;
        // begin request
        httpReq.open("GET",args);
        httpReq.send();
        return true;
    }
    function responder(httpResponse,form){
        // use the $separ variable from PHP
<?php echo '        var separator="'.$separ.'";'."\n";?>
        if(httpResponse.responseText[0]==separator){
            var returned=httpResponse.responseText.split(separator); // separation
            form.Tile.value=returned[1];
            form.TileScore.value=returned[2];
        }else{form.submit();}
    }
//]]>
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p class="notice">javascript required to use more than one form</p>
<form method="get" action="" id="form1">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="1"/>
<input type="text" name="RFID"<?php if($form==1){echo ' value="'.$rfid.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="Tile"<?php if($form==1){echo ' value="'.$tile.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="TileScore"<?php if($form==1){echo ' value="'.$tileScore.'"';}?>/>
<input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<form method="get" action="" id="form2">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="RFID"<?php if($form==2){echo ' value="'.$rfid.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="Tile"<?php if($form==2){echo ' value="'.$tile.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="TileScore"<?php if($form==2){echo ' value="'.$tileScore.'"';}?>/>
<input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
<form method="get" action="" id="form3">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="3"/>
<input type="text" name="RFID"<?php if($form==3){echo ' value="'.$rfid.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="Tile"<?php if($form==3){echo ' value="'.$tile.'"';}?>/>
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" name="TileScore"<?php if($form==3){echo ' value="'.$tileScore.'"';}?>/>
<input type ="submit" value="submit"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php }?>
```

Comment: @joel.Conway Awesome, I spent quite a lot of time on it, glad it was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to fill text fields on the page based on the input of another text field on the page, you need AJAX or to dump all possibilities of the text fields into javascript variables on the page from PHP (ew).

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Have it call a PHP script that returns a JSON object that holds the field data based on the RFID text field.

Comment: Ajax != jQuery, link to a site about ajax not just jQuery